# How do I remove the icon and show the label of a KML placemark in Google Maps JavaScript API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, kmz

I'm using Google Maps JavaScript API and loading a KML layer to display points.

I want it to display the labels but not the blue point markers.

Here is what it looks like now:

[image: Map of New York with blue point markers.]

The blue markers are where I want the labels to be.

Here is the relevant section from the KML:

```
<Style id="normalPlacemark">
    <IconStyle>
        <Icon><href>https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Transparent.png</href></Icon>
    </IconStyle>
    <LineStyle>
        <gx:labelVisibility>1</gx:labelVisibility>
    </LineStyle>
</Style>
<Folder>
  <name>Labels</name>
  <Placemark>
    <name>3H</name>
    <Point><coordinates>-74.784880,41.752639,0</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>4F</name>
    <Point><coordinates>-74.985419,42.619435,0</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>4G</name>
    <Point><coordinates>-74.444085,42.514970,0</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>4H</name>
    <Point><coordinates>-74.126351,42.508052,0</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>4O</name>
    <Point><coordinates>-75.214074,42.230072,0</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>4P</name>
    <Point><coordinates>-74.795944,42.201073,0</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>4R</name>
    <Point><coordinates>-74.418647,42.266143,0</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>4W</name>
    <Point><coordinates>-75.115810,41.965973,0</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>6G</name>
    <Point><coordinates>-76.005867,43.998634,0</coordinates></Point>
  </Placemark>
</Folder>
```

I've tried messing with this in every way I can think of but I think I just don't understand KML well enough. How do I get these blue markers to stop appearing and the labels to start appearing?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer

Comment: @MrUpsidown Just read through that documentation. It says IconStyle, Icon, and href are supported (and I can gaurantee that the "../transparent.png" is a valid file, it uses the full URL in the actual code). It doesn't mention anything about the label at all. How do I get the icon to not show and the label to show?

EDIT: Also I went ahead and removed the tags the API ignores from the original post.

Comment: What is the full URL? What is a *label* anyway? The doc also mentions that `<Point>` **will** be rendered as a Marker.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Sorry. I just edited the original post to have a full URL. It's just a fully transparent png. By label I mean text on the map. I want the names of these placemarks to appear on the Google Map similarly to how they appear if you import the KML into Google Earth, only without the icon (or with the icon fully transparent). Or just any way of having text appear on the map at certain coordinates.

Comment: Your best option would *probably* be to use a parser like [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) (and not the KmlLayer) and to create [Advanced Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/overview) with the design of your choice.

Comment: [`<LabelStyle>` is not supported by KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer) (see the table at the bottom)

Comment: Possibly related question (displays marker labels with geoxml3): [Change font size of placemark's name when zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69582885/change-font-size-of-placemarks-name-when-zooming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to display the Placemark names as labels using [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) (based of the related question: [Change font size of placemark's name when zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69582885/change-font-size-of-placemarks-name-when-zooming)) would be to create a custom `createMarker` function for geoxml3 that uses your transparent icon and sets the `Marker`'s label to the name text of the placemark:

```
function createMarker(placemark, doc) {
  var markerOptions = {
    optimized: true,
    clickable: false,
    position: placemark.latlng,
    map: map,
    label: {
      text: placemark.name,
      fontSize: "18px"
    },
    icon: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Transparent.png",
    visible: true,
  };
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
  doc.markers.push(marker);
  return marker;
}
```

You could continue to use `KmlLayer` to display the polygons, or use geoxml3 to display those as well.

[image: screenshot of resulting map with your posted KML (modified so the labels have a style)]

**code snippet:**

```js
var geoXml;
var map;

function createMarker(placemark, doc) {
  var markerOptions = {
    optimized: true,
    clickable: false,
    position: placemark.latlng,
    map: map,
    label: {
      text: placemark.name,
      fontSize: "18px"
    },
    icon: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Transparent.png",
    visible: true,
  };

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
  doc.markers.push(marker);

  return marker;
}

function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(105.4009049697155, 45.9307395294156),
    zoom: 15,
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions
  );
  geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
    map: map,
    singleInfoWindow: false,
    processStyles: false,
    createMarker: createMarker,
    afterParse: useTheData,
  });
  geoXml.parseKmlString(kmlString);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "zoom_changed", function() {
    console.log("zoom=" + map.getZoom());
    if (map.getZoom() < 7) {
      geoXml.docs[0].markers.forEach(function(placemark) {
        if (placemark.getMap() != null) {
          var label = placemark.getLabel();
          console.log(label);
          if (typeof label === 'string') {
            var labelObj = {};
            labelObj.text = label;
            labelObj.fontSize = "0px";
            placemark.setLabel(labelObj);
          } else {
            label.fontSize = "0px";
            placemark.setLabel(label);
          }

        }
      });
    } else {
      geoXml.docs[0].markers.forEach(function(placemark) {
        if (placemark.getMap() != null) {
          var label = placemark.getLabel();
          // console.log(label);
          if (typeof label === 'string') {
            var labelObj = {};
            labelObj.text = label;
            label.fontSize = "18px";
            placemark.setLabel(labelObj);
          } else {
            label.fontSize = "18px";
            placemark.setLabel(label);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });

}

function useTheData(doc) {
  for (var i = 0; i < doc[0].placemarks.length; i++) {
    var placemark = doc[0].placemarks[i];
    if (placemark.polygon) {
      placemark.polygon.normalStyle = {
        strokeColor: "#ffff00",
        strokeWeight: 1,
        strokeOpacity: 0,
        fillColor: "#ffff00",
        fillOpacity: 0,
      };
      placemark.polygon.setOptions(placemark.polygon.normalStyle);
    }
  }
}
var kmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"><Document><Style id="normalPlacemark"><IconStyle><Icon><href>https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Transparent.png</href></Icon></IconStyle><LineStyle><gx:labelVisibility>1</gx:labelVisibility></LineStyle><LabelStyle><color>ff0000cc</color><colorMode>random</colorMode><scale>1.5</scale></LabelStyle></Style><Folder><name>Labels</name><Placemark><name>3H</name><styleUrl>#normalPlacemark</styleUrl><Point><coordinates>-74.784880,41.752639,0</coordinates></Point></Placemark><Placemark><name>4F</name><styleUrl>#normalPlacemark</styleUrl><Point><coordinates>-74.985419,42.619435,0</coordinates></Point></Placemark><Placemark><name>4G</name><styleUrl>#normalPlacemark</styleUrl><Point><coordinates>-74.444085,42.514970,0</coordinates></Point></Placemark><Placemark><name>4H</name><styleUrl>#normalPlacemark</styleUrl><Point><coordinates>-74.126351,42.508052,0</coordinates></Point></Placemark><Placemark><name>4O</name><styleUrl>#normalPlacemark</styleUrl><Point><coordinates>-75.214074,42.230072,0</coordinates></Point></Placemark><Placemark><name>4P</name><styleUrl>#normalPlacemark</styleUrl><Point><coordinates>-74.795944,42.201073,0</coordinates></Point></Placemark><Placemark><name>4R</name><styleUrl>#normalPlacemark</styleUrl><Point><coordinates>-74.418647,42.266143,0</coordinates></Point></Placemark><Placemark><name>4W</name><styleUrl>#normalPlacemark</styleUrl><Point><coordinates>-75.115810,41.965973,0</coordinates></Point></Placemark><Placemark><name>6G</name><styleUrl>#normalPlacemark</styleUrl><Point><coordinates>-76.005867,43.998634,0</coordinates></Point></Placemark></Folder></Document></kml>';

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Import KML</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/geocodezip/geoxml3/master/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/geocodezip/geoxml3/master/ProjectedOverlay.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**modified KML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
    <Document>
        <Style id="normalPlacemark">
            <IconStyle>
                <Icon>
                    <href>https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Transparent.png</href>
                </Icon>
            </IconStyle>
            <LineStyle>
                <gx:labelVisibility>1</gx:labelVisibility>
            </LineStyle>
            <LabelStyle>
                <color>ff0000cc</color>
                <colorMode>random</colorMode>
                <scale>1.5</scale>
            </LabelStyle>
        </Style>
        <Folder>
            <name>Labels</name>
            <Placemark>
                <name>3H</name>
                <styleUrl>#normalPlacemark</styleUrl> <!-- missing -->
                <Point>
                    <coordinates>-74.784880,41.752639,0</coordinates>
                </Point>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>4F</name>
                <styleUrl>#normalPlacemark</styleUrl>
                <Point>
                    <coordinates>-74.985419,42.619435,0</coordinates>
                </Point>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>4G</name>
                <styleUrl>#normalPlacemark</styleUrl>
                <Point>
                    <coordinates>-74.444085,42.514970,0</coordinates>
                </Point>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>4H</name>
                <styleUrl>#normalPlacemark</styleUrl>
                <Point>
                    <coordinates>-74.126351,42.508052,0</coordinates>
                </Point>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>4O</name>
                <styleUrl>#normalPlacemark</styleUrl>
                <Point>
                    <coordinates>-75.214074,42.230072,0</coordinates>
                </Point>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>4P</name>
                <styleUrl>#normalPlacemark</styleUrl>
                <Point>
                    <coordinates>-74.795944,42.201073,0</coordinates>
                </Point>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>4R</name>
                <styleUrl>#normalPlacemark</styleUrl>
                <Point>
                    <coordinates>-74.418647,42.266143,0</coordinates>
                </Point>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
                <name>4W</name>
                <styleUrl>#normalPlacemark</styleUrl>
                <Point>
                    <coordinates>-75.115810,41.965973,0</coordinates>
                </Point>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
    
            <name>6G</name>
                <styleUrl>#normalPlacemark</styleUrl>
                <Point>
                    <coordinates>-76.005867,43.998634,0</coordinates>
                </Point>
            </Placemark>
        </Folder>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

[live version](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_20230525_PointLabelsFromKml.html)

Comment: This works, thank you!! But I still don't understand how geoxml3 works really, is there a documentation for it somewhere?

Comment: What documentation exists is in github: [READ.ME](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3/blob/master/README.md), [ProjectHome](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3/blob/wiki/ProjectHome.md), [ParserReference](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3/blob/wiki/ParserReference.md), [JsonObjects](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3/blob/wiki/JsonObjects.md), [Usage](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3/blob/wiki/Usage.md)